# save some data in mysql on my server by curl

Tags: php, mysql, php-curl

I want to save some data in mysql on my server by curl, my code is something like this
my curl

```
  function  verify_data_on_server 
   ($user_id,$user_name,$user_code,$user_type,$user_url,$ user_email)

 {  

 $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://myurl.com/apis/verified_user.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query(array('user_id' => $user_id,'user_name' => $user_name,'user_code' => $user_code,'user_type' => $user_type,'user_url' => $user_url,'user_email' => $user_email)));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
  if ($server_output == "status") { echo "done"; } else { echo "fail!";}     
 }  ?>
```

but data not save . please guide me where im wrong ?

I want to save some data in mysql on my server by curl, I tried a lot but didn't get any success

Comment: Looks like saving to database is done in `verified_user.php`, so we would need to see what that file does. What errors do you get?

Comment: The code you posted would produce a _parse error_

Comment: brombeer  I have need to create Verified_user.php. asked you for the same

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean?
you can't save data by cURl, you can send requests by cURL.
but I suppose that you want to send a request to your server by cURL and store some data within cURL request.
so you need a function or code or stuff for getting some data from requests and storing data in the database.

you can get all data within requests by $_REQUEST

example

```
$user_id=$_REQUEST['user_id'];
$user_name=$_REQUEST['user_name'];
```

and stuff ...
then you can store these data in your database.

Comment: im doing like as in Verified_user.php

`<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db_name');
$user_id=$_REQUEST['user_id'];
$user_name=$_REQUEST['user_name'];
mysqli_query($con,"insert into verification_user(user_id,user_name)values
('$user_id','$user_name');
exit;
?>
`
but not inserting data db.

Comment: where is you called your verify_data_on_server function?
can you send your full code?

Comment: '<?php  $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db_name'); $user_id=$_REQUEST['user_id']; $user_name=$_REQUEST['user_name']; mysqli_query($con,"insert into verification_user(user_id,user_name)values ('$user_id','$user_name'); exit; ?>'